# Поисковой запрос и SEO

Tags: seo

Некоторые сайты подставляют поисковой запрос google, yandex и тд в ссылку на сайт, описание и в поисковую строку на своем сайте, даже если на сайте нет контента соответствующего запросу. За это отвечает сам посиковик? Или нужно с сайтом сделать какие-то манипуляции что б получить такой функционал?
Для примера это сайты по поиску работы, маркетплейсы.

Comment: Мало что понял, что Вы хотите, могу из опыта сказать что если Вам нужно получить ссылку с выдачи по запросу которому страница не релевантна, можно разместить с различных сайтов ссылки, так чтобы анкором был запрос. Если озадачиться то можно добиться такого результата, вот только зачем? Если по идее можно делать релевантную запросу страницу и которая будет полезна человеку который её искал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я позволю себе дать ответ с точки зрения Гугл.

Вероятно вы имеете ввиду так называемое **[Окно поиска по сайту](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox)**, которое реализуется с использованием структурированных данных. Проверьте следующие шаги которые рекомендует Гугл для представления Окна поиска в богатых результатах поиска:

> **Как реализовать окно поиска по сайту**
>
> Как добиться того, чтобы при
> появлении вашего контента в результатах поиска Google показывалось
> окно поиска:
>
> **Интегрируйте поисковую систему в свой сайт или в приложение Android**.
> Введя поисковый запрос в дополнительном окне, пользователь будет
> переадресован на сайт или в приложение и увидит страницу с
> результатами. Чтобы эта функция работала, вам понадобится настроить
> поисковую систему.
>
> **Сайты**. Добавьте поисковую систему на сайт. Она будет перенаправлять
> запросы пользователей на нужную страницу с учетом синтаксиса ваших
> структурированных данных. Поисковая система должна поддерживать
> запросы в кодировке UTF-8.
>
> **Добавьте элемент структурированных данных WebSite** на главную страницу
> сайта. Приложение обязательно должно быть связано с сайтом, даже если
> он состоит из одной страницы. В противном случае поиск работать не
> будет. Дополнительные рекомендации: Добавляйте эту разметку только на
> стартовую страницу сайта. Всегда указывайте одно свойство SearchAction
> для поиска по сайту, а другое – для поиска по приложению (если
> применимо). Обратите внимание, что указывать свойство SearchAction для
> сайта обязательно, даже если поиск в приложении для вас приоритетен.
> Это необходимо, чтобы пользователи, которые отправили запрос не с
> телефона Android или не установили ваше приложение, могли перейти к
> списку результатов на сайте.
>
> **Убедитесь в правильности структурированных данных**, воспользовавшись
> инструментом проверки расширенных результатов.
>
> **Проверьте, как работает ваша поисковая система**. Для этого скопируйте
> URL WebSite.potentialAction.target из структурированных данных,
> подставьте вместо {search_term_string} тестовый запрос и выполните
> поиск по этому URL в браузере. Например, если у сайта адрес
> example.com и вы хотите протестировать запрос kittens (котята), URL
> будет таким: https://www.example.com/search/?q=kittens.
>
> **Укажите предпочтительный канонический URL главной страницы домена**,
> добавив атрибут rel="canonical" на все варианты главной страницы. Это
> поможет алгоритму Google Поиска выбрать корректный URL для разметки.
> Обратите внимание, что ваш сервер должен поддерживать кодировку UTF-8.

Проверьте документацию Гугл на английском языке **[Обзор программируемой поисковой системы](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview)**. Обратите внимание на тот факт что **[Пользовательский поиск JSON API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)** использует спецификацию **[OpenSearch 1.1](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1)**.

Для создания релевантных структурированных данных может быть полезным изучить руководство Гугл **[Общие рекомендации по использованию структурированных данных](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)**, в которых, среди прочего сказано следующее:

> **Обратите внимание, что Google не гарантирует показ вашего контента** в
> результатах поиска, даже если инструмент проверки расширенных
> результатов не выявил ошибок. Причины могут быть следующими:  ...
> Страница не соответствует требованиям, описанным в этой статье,
> правилам в отношении контента определенного типа или рекомендациям для
> веб-мастеров.

Это означает, что богатые результаты Гугл, основанные на структурированных данных, могут быть недоступны если эти данные установлены на веб-странице с содержанием противоречащим какому то руководству Гугл для веб-мастеров. Может иметь смысл использовать рекомендации Гугл из их руководства **[Введение в поисковую оптимизацию](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=ru)**.